# Traditional ASP.Net WebForms vs ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to favor webforms over MVC](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95212/when-to-favor-webforms-over-mvc)

ASP.Net MVC has been around for some time now. The latest one, i.e MVC3 comes with Razor View Engine.

My question: How long is traditional ASP.Net here to stay. Does Microsoft have any plans to eliminate it in aid of ASP.Net MVC in the future and will the next release of VS incorporate it?

Also, I would like to know if there is any merit of traditional over ASP.Net MVC, other than the controls-aid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems only natural that Microsoft will try to push mvc adoption for ASP.NET, to catch up with the competition. Since the early days of ASP.NET MVC, most articles on ASP.NET on [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532094.aspx?sdmr=asp&sdmi=topics) seem to feature the framework as do most articles from the [news and community content section](http://www.asp.net/community) of asp.net.

I consider the above strong hints, but nothing more. Even if pushing the mvc approach is evident, that doesn't mean that the event driven approach will stop being focal to ASP.NET anytime soon. Microsoft were extremely late in adopting MVC so they are now pushing hard to fill the blanks.

Also note that I'm not suggesting that event-driven is bad and mvc is good. Both architectures have their valid uses and distinct merits. What was pretty bad, was that up until recently there wasn't an easy way to implement mvc on ASP.NET so people would have to get extra creative with the event driven approach in cases where mvc would be more appropriate.

So, no I don't see Microsoft giving up the event driven approach in favor of mvc, it doesn't make sense.