# Is ASP.NET MVC too much overhead for smaller projects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I will be honest I don't really know much about MVC other than the stuff you can [read online in 5 minutes.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started)  Unfortunately this doesn't really tell me whether its suited to smaller projects or not.

I also read [this related question and its chosen answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95212/when-to-favor-asp-net-webforms-over-mvc), but the business perspective is not a concern in this case for me as I am the only one making it. The next answer proceeds to say why it is more flexible. Sure, that's great. But my question is again, if its an ideal choice for a small project.

For example I would rather use winforms to make a simple mockup of a small desktop program than do it on WPF because of the overhead of custom styling.

So I have a project that will essentially  have about 6-8 pages that read excel files and user input use that to pull a bit of data from databases and output  resulting excel files.

I will be the only one working on this project.  If I used webforms I would expect it to take no more than 2-3 weeks.

Now I am 100% comfortable with webforms. And I know its easy to do a small project in webforms.

But I have only heard good things about MVC so I am seriously considering it.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: @gnat: Meh, I think that's a bit unfair.  While the wording of the title makes it sound like an opinion-based question, I think the core question is answerable without this being a problem.  Specifically, whether or not, for small projects, MVC has more overhead than WebForms.  There is a little bit of subjectiveness in this question, but it strikes me as [Good Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  The good thing about this question is that the OP provided a narrow enough X vs Y question for it to actually be answerable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To MVC or not MVC, that is the question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224638/to-mvc-or-not-mvc-that-is-the-question)

Comment: My question is more specific than MVC vs not MVC. Mine is specific to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that it's not any more overhead than webforms.

The first time you use MVC it'll definitely be slower because you haven't used it before, but once you get the hang of it there's not really any difference in development speed.

My advice, go for it, get stuck in, you'll dig it after a while.

Answer (score 4):

MVC is a proven design pattern for web applications.The asp.net mvc provide loose coupling between the components thats why it is preffered in large enterprise level application, the web forms are preffered for small projects because wbe forms provide fast development I personally used mvc for many projects and I love it. I've seen the light and I will never go back to WebForms or ever suggest someone to work in WebForms no matter application is small or big.

Its obvious the asp.net mvc is more flexible than asp.net webforms in general.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use Winforms vs WPF as an analogy to WebForms vs MVC. The former two are VERY different from one another (if you take WPF to the MVVM extreme anyway).

MVC is actually simpler than WebForms in many respects. If anything it is lighter weight and promotes faster development through a much simpler model of development. You also have the advantage of being able to use the much nicer Razor syntax which I don't believe you can use with WebFroms. MVC has very nice HTML Helpers to spit out the common HTML stuff and it has very nice, simple data binding.

There is also no hacky Viewstate. I personally don't miss not having event handling in my code behind, I will take an Action method on a controller any day.

Also, your application may end up growing or changing requirements. MVC will help you there. It will also give you a more marketable skillset because the industry is moving in the MVC direction.

I would never opt to use WebForms if I had the choice (which I currently don't) regardless of the size of the project.